# Update the part of the redux store only if the value is not null

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following code in my reducer. It works fine except that when `comment.parentPostId` is null. I wonder how I can run `[comment.parentPostId]` part only when `comment.parentPostId` is not null.

As a solution, I can define two reducers, one per each condition. But, it does not seem like a solid approach. Any suggestions?

```
 case POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
     const comment = action.payload.normalizedData;
     return {
         ...state,
         loading: false,
         editing: false,
         alignPerspectives: {
             ...state.alignPerspectives,
             [comment.submissionId]: {
                 ...state.alignPerspectives[comment.submissionId],
                 discussionPosts: [...state.alignPerspectives[comment.submissionId].discussionPosts, comment.id]
             }
         },
         discussionPosts: {
             ...state.discussionPosts,
             [comment.id]: comment,
             [comment.parentPostId]: {
                 ...state.discussionPosts[comment.parentPostId],
                 childPosts: [...state.discussionPosts[comment.parentPostId].childPosts, comment.id]
             }

         }
     };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always split your reducer and delgate some part of the process to the other reducer as mentioned here https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/splitting-reducer-logic

OR

You can use a ternary operator to check if it's a valid value and return the state object accordingly

```
case POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
    const comment = action.payload.normalizedData;

    return comment.parentPostId ? {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        editing: false,
        alignPerspectives: {
            ...state.alignPerspectives,
            [comment.submissionId]: {
                ...state.alignPerspectives[comment.submissionId],
                discussionPosts: [...state.alignPerspectives[comment.submissionId].discussionPosts, comment.id]
            }
        },
        discussionPosts: {
            ...state.discussionPosts,
            [comment.id]: comment,
            [comment.parentPostId]: {
                ...state.discussionPosts[comment.parentPostId],
                childPosts: [...state.discussionPosts[comment.parentPostId].childPosts, comment.id]
            }

        }
    } : {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        editing: false,
        alignPerspectives: {
            ...state.alignPerspectives,
            [comment.submissionId]: {
                ...state.alignPerspectives[comment.submissionId],
                discussionPosts: [...state.alignPerspectives[comment.submissionId].discussionPosts, comment.id]
            }
        },
        discussionPosts: {
            ...state.discussionPosts,
            [comment.id]: comment,
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps !